# Replacing the Fibre of a Fibration

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fibration

This was a question I first asked on stack exchange, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3277807/replacing-the-fibre-of-a-fibration). In my head it seems like a fairly reasonable thing to ask for, but I'm not aware of any construction in the literature.

Let $p:E\rightarrow X$ be a Serre fibration over a pointed, connected CW complex $X$ with strict fibre a CW complex $F=p^{-1}(\ast)$. Given another space $F'$ and a homotopy equivalence $F\simeq F'$, is it possible to construct a Serre fibration $p':E'\rightarrow X$ with strict fibre $F'=p'^{-1}(\ast)$? If $E'$ exists, is it then possible to extend the homotopy equivalence $F\simeq F'$ to a fibre homotopy equivalence $E\simeq E'$ over $X$?

If you assume some extra structure on the fibration $p$ and the homotopy equivalence $F\simeq F'$ then things work out fairly easily, but I'm interested in the more general case.

Really I would like both questions to be taken together, since as pointed out in the comments, the projection $X\times F'\rightarrow X$ trivially satisfies the requirements of the first question alone, and such an answer is not exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: can you please recall what "strict fiber" means?

Comment: The simplicial analogue of this is closely related to univalence, and is shown in Theorem 3.4.1 of [*The simplicial model of Univalent Foundations (after Voevodsky)*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1211.2851.pdf) (Kapulkin–Lumsdaine 2012). Specifically, in the triangular-prism diagram in the proof of 3.4.1, take $B$ to be your $X$, $A$ to be the point of $X$, $\bar{E_2}$ to be your $E$ (so $E_2$ is the fiber $F$), and $E_1$ to be your $F'$. The extension $\bar{E_1}$ constructed there is then your desired $E'$. I don’t think it’s quite trivial to adapt the proof to the topological setting, though.

Comment: @GaelMeigniez, by 'strict fibre' I mean the inverse image $p^{-1}(\ast)\subseteq E$, with $\ast\in X$ denoting the supplied basepoint.

Comment: For the first question you presumably want to avoid a trivial answer such as taking the projection $F'\times X \to X$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make the construction as follows. There are three steps.

First make a Serre fibration over the unit interval, pi:T->I=[0,1] such that the fibre over 0 (resp. 1) is F (resp. F').  You will find how to make this in the general case; for example, for F=1 point and F'=the interval, here is a proof that the triangle does it.

Consider in the plane the triangle T: 0<=y<=x<=1 and the projection pi(x,y)=x. Given a CW-complex A, a continuous map from A to T:a->(x_0(a),y_0(a)) and a homotopy (x_t(a)) (0<=t<=1), consider K={(a,t)\in AxI/x_t(a)=0} and K_0=(Ax0)\cap K. On the complement (Ax0)\K_0 you have the slope function s_0(a):=y_0(a)/x_0(a); extend it to a continuous function s from (AxI)\K to I; the wanted homotopy is (a,t)->(x_t(a),s(a,t)x_t(a)) for (a,t)\notin K and (a,t)->(0,0) for (a,t)\in K. Hence, pi is a Serre fibration.

Second, let $f:X\rightarrow X$ be homotopic to the identity and contract some
neighborhood $N$ of $*$ onto $*$. Pulling back your fibration $p$ through $f$, you are reduced to the case where $p$ is a projection $F\times N\rightarrow N$ over $N$.

Third, consider a function $g: N\rightarrow I$ whose value is $0$ on $\partial N$ and $1$ on $*$;  define $E'$ over $N$
as the amalgamated product of $T$ with $N$ over $pi$ and $g$; define $E'$ as $E$ over $(X-N)$. If you have chosen $N$ to retract by deformation on $*$, then this $E'$ will have the property you want.

Maybe there is a more elegant way to present the construction (i'm not an expert in homotopy theory nor cw-complexes)

Comment: Thanks, Gael. If you work out that last step I'd be i'd be interested in seeing it.

Comment: Gael, does the projection of a right triangle onto its base not satisfy that?

Comment: After Peter's comment, I have merged my partial answers. Thanks, Peter.

Comment: Could someone elaborate on how to produce a fibration over $[0,1]$ with both $F$ and $F'$ as fibers, starting just from a homotopy equivalence $f$ between $F$ and $F'$? The triangle example doesn't seem that informative to me; it suggests that sometimes the mapping cylinder of $f$ will do the trick, but that doesn't work in general (e.g. it fails when $f$ is a constant map from a disk to itself).

Comment: The question raised in my previous comment is addressed here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453933/are-all-homotopy-equivalences-realized-by-fibrations-over-0-1